# str_replace php

Tags: php

Как сделать замену по шаблону:
слово: и 3 цифры

Comment: Опишите детальнее что Вам нужно. Возможно Вам придётся использовать `preg_replace()`

Comment: нужно в файле css убрать цвет фона то есть нужно заменить background:#000 на пустоту.
Хотя получается могут быть еще буквы как можно организовать если к примеру будет background: #ff2245;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$newStr = preg_replace('/background:.+?;/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$newStr = preg_replace( '/background(-color)?:[^;]+;/', '', $str );
```